# codeigniter htaccess with multiple applications

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have front end application and backend application like

/system/

/application/

```
   /front/

   /admin/

index.php

admin.php

.htaccess
```

I want my url like http://example.com/news/article1 (for site)
http://example.com/news/admin (for admin)

In .htaccess I have written

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the user types just "admin".
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin$ admin\.php [L,QSA]

# If the user enter in any admin section, like "admin/section".
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin\/(.*)$ admin\.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

the front end is working fine but when I enter mydomain.com/admin it is throwing 404 not found error. Please help me.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that good with .htaccess, but from the [CI website](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), you can use this for your .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and then use [routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to rewrite your urls. Much easier than trying to do it in .htaccess files